# Find the spectrum (classification) of a given operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let operator $A$: $C([1,2],\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow C([1,2],\mathbb{C})$
$$(Af)(t)=\frac{1}{t}\int_1^t\tau f(\tau)d\tau-f(t)$$
I want to find the spectrum (and the resolvent) of this operator. I found the resolvent solving $(A-\lambda I)=y $ and I see that the resolvent doesn't exist for $\lambda = -1$, so $\lambda = -1 \in \sigma(A)$. I'm wondering about the classification of the point of the spectrum.
I solved $(A-\lambda I)=0$ and get the point spectrum $\sigma_p=\emptyset$, but I don't know how to check continuous spectrum $\sigma_c$ and the residual spectrum $\sigma_r$. As I understand, I need to show that for $\lambda = -1: \overline {Im (A-\lambda I)}\neq C([1,2],\mathbb{C})$ (sorry if I'm wrong), and I'm also not sure what to do for $\lambda \neq -1$.

Comment: Let $(Uf)(t)= tf(t).$ Then $$(UAU^{-1}f)(t)= \int_1^tf(s)\,ds-f(t)$$ The new operator has the same spectrum and looks slightly easier. The operator has the form $-I$ plus the antiderivative of $f$ which vanishes at $1.$ So it suffices to study the spectrum of the antiderivative, i.e. to solve the equation $f=\lambda f'$, $f(1)=0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use Arzela-Ascoli Theorem to show that $Bf(t)=\frac{1}{t}\int_1^t\tau f(\tau)d\tau$ defines  a compact operator. So non-zero points in the spectrum of $B$ are all eigen values. Since $A=B-I$ it follows that all points other than $-1$ are eigen values. Points  in the closure of the  range of $B$ are all absolutely continuous, so this is not equal to $C[1,2]$. So for $\lambda = -1: \overline {Im (A-\lambda I)}\neq C([1,2],\mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 1):

The subtraction of $f(t)$ just shifts the spectrum by $\pm1$, so let's disregard it.

Next, the multiplication by $\tau$ inside the integral is a multiplication operator, and the whole is composition of that multiplication operator with a Volterra-type operator $Vf(t)=\int_1^t f(\tau)\,d\tau$. It suffices to show that this Volterra operator is compact, since pre- or post-composition of a bounded (=continuous) operator with a compact operator is again compact.

... Oh, and, the spectrum of a Volterra operator is just $\{0\}$... :)